# Equivalent expressions produce different results in a function?

Tags: haskell, integration

I have a function (exercise 10.11 in Thompson's *The Craft of Functional Programming*) which computes an approximation to the value of the definite integral of a function over a domain (a, b). It might not be the most elegant function, but I'm still a a beginner:

```
import Data.Ratio (Rational, (%), denominator, numerator)
type R = Rational

integrate :: (R -> R) -> R -> (R, R) -> R       
integrate f d (a, b) = foldr (+) 0 $ zipWith (*) (map f [a, a + d..b]) (widths d)
 where widths :: R -> [R]
       widths = \n -> n : widths n

eval :: R -> Double       
eval = \r -> (/) (fromIntegral $ numerator r) (fromIntegral $ denominator r)
```

For instance,

```
eval $ integrate (\x -> 20 + x^2) (1%10000) (-3%1, 3%1) = 
 ~> 138.00290001
```

Now, `widths d` should be equivalent to the expression `[d..]`. However, if I replace widths by [d..] in integrate, my function outputs incorrect values. For instance:

```
integrate' :: (R -> R) -> R -> (R, R) -> R       
integrate' f d (a, b) = foldr (+) 0 $ zipWith (*) (map f [a, a+d..b]) [d..]

eval $ integrate' (\x -> 20 + x^2) (1%10000) (-3%1, 3%1)
 ~> 41400870141.0029
```

Why is this?

Comment: Rather than "**EDIT: Solved**", on this site, the etiquette is to mark the correct answer (in this case, mine, as it's the only one and you think the question's solved) as "accepted" by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: You could have used `repeat d` instead of `widths d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the two statements aren't equivalent.  Consider what happens when I call `widths d`:

```
widths d = d : widths d
         = d : d : widths d
         ...
         = [d, d, d, ...]
```

In other words, you get an infinite list of `d`s.  However, `[d..]` returns the list `[d, d+1, d+2, ...]`.  To get an infinite list of `d`s, you can write `[d,d..]`;  in general, `[d,d+n..]` creates the infinite list `[d, d+n, d+2*n, ...]`.  More idiomatically, one would generally write `repeat d`; repeat has the signature `a -> [a]`, and just repeats its argument infinitely.

**Edit:** Also, some style, etc., points: `function = \x -> ...` is the same as `function x = ...` in all cases.  And there's no particular reason to write your `eval` function with a prefix `/`; I'd write it `eval r = (fromIntegral $ numerator r) / (fromIntegral $ denominator r)`; in actual fact, however, I'd just use the `fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a` function instead of `eval`.  You can also replace `foldr (+) 0` with `sum`.  And you don't need to create an infinite list of `d`s and then multiply everything; more simply, you could just have `sum . map (* d) $ map f [a, a + d..b]`.  Of course, you can then distribute this out, and have

```
integrate'' :: (R -> R) -> R -> (R,R) -> R
integrate'' f d (a,b) = d * (sum $ map f [a, a+d .. b])`
```

And then we have

```
> fromRational $ integrate'' (\x -> 20 + x^2) (1%10000) (-3%1, 3%1) 
138.00290001
```

Comment: @danportin: check out the tool hlint (for style suggestions and catching these kinds of things) and the search engine hoogle (for finding builtin functions with a certain type signature)

Comment: Thanks for the style tips. I know that I could replace 'foldr (+) 0]' with sum, and lambda expressions by explicit arguments in the function definitions. However, I just learned about them; so I have been using them.

However, you're right that 'map (*d) (map f [a, a+d..b' is cleaner and more efficient than what I wrote. Thanks for pointing out that I don't need to generate an infinite list of widths.